# Online count down timer/alarm clock that gives a nudge when a set time is up?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there an online count down timer/alarm clock that gives you nudge when a set time is up?

**I do not want it to play a sound, but rather give me a notification that I can see (like when you get a msn message)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Aero Timer extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paaapjjeilbadekejlnanfngpmcndbln?hl=en-GB#)

You can either do a count down or set a time for the alarm to go off. The extension icon shakes when the time is up and it also sends you a desktop notification. The only down side is that does play a sound as well, which at the moment, you cannot turn off.

Comment: thx the one at aerotimer.com works great

Answer (score 1):

http://www.timer-tab.com will do that on Google Chrome / Chromium. Check out the options.

Note that you can't disable sound notification.

**Disclosure:** I wrote this web app.

Comment: why don't you add a "tab notification" like the one we have on messenger?

Comment: what do you mean whith tab notification?

Comment: For example, if I switch a window, it will "blink". I've seen some webapps do that so I think it is possible

Comment: are you using IE9?

Comment: no I use chrome

Comment: hm actually Timer Tab should "blink" then when the time is up